# In Django, how could I in a single query get total row count based on distinct field values?

Tags: python, django, count, distinct, django-queryset

This seems like a scenario that would be pretty common, so I'm really hoping someone might have a quick answer for me.

Consider the scenario where I have multiple sites and multiple companies per site for which I am gathering leads.  So I have a lead table where each record has the following fields: *date*, *site*, *companies* (a lead can go to multiple companies), *user*, *comment*.  Now I need to generate a summary the gives the total number of leads that each company got on each site for each date.

So basically I need a query that will give me the total number of rows for each company on each site.  Is this even possible to do in a single query?

Alternatively, we can easily loop through the sites, in which case we would only need to count the number of rows that belonged to each company, given a particular site.

Appreciate any thoughts.  Here's a sample model to work with:

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    comment = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Posting your model definitions would really help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've been fiddling around with this, and I believe I have come up with a solution that produces the results I'm after.  Given the model above, I'm using the following:

```
Lead.objects.values('site', 'companies').annotate(Count('id'))
```

This yields a list of dictionaries, one dictionary per unique site/company combination, each containing an *id__count* key that contains the total number of rows for that particular combination of site and company.  And if one lead has multiple companies associated with it, a separate dictionary is produced for each.

In our actual model, we have different types of leads as well and an additional field *type*.  So if I wanted to take that into consideration as well, I would simply add a *type* field to the model and use the following:

```
Lead.objects.values('site', 'companies', 'type').annotate(Count('id'))
```

Using this, I would get one dictionary per site, per type, per company, each with its own count.  Django is pretty smart!

Anyway, basic question I'm sure, but I couldn't quite find anything that addressed it.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) queryset method.:

```
Lead.objects.distinct('companies', 'site', 'date').count()
```

You can pass what ever field ( or fields ) into distinct to get a distinct records in that row. Then you can simply call [count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count) on it.

Comment: Tried this, and it looks like this gives me a count of how many different groups of rows, where each of these is unique.  But I need to know the count of the rows in each group.  Think I found the solution, but appreciate your input.